# How can I create cross-reference when a sigil is required for referring but not for defining?

Tags: xtext

In my DSL, I have something similar to:

```
x = 14
y = $x + 1
```

So an element is *defined* with just its name, but when *referred* to, some sigil must be added. Any whitespace between the sigil and the name is forbidden when referencing the element.

**How can I do this in Xtext, while still allowing cross-reference between these elements?**

Because it seems to me that I either have to use two different terminals for this - one to match `x` and the other to match `$x` - but then how would the cross-reference mechanism associate them together? Or alternatively, if I define:

```
ElementRef: '$' [Element|ELEMENT_NAME];
```

then Xtext will allow whitespace between the sigil and the name, which is illegal in my DSL. I guess an option such as "do not accept whitespace at this point" would be great, but I could not find anything in the Xtext documentation about something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a datatype rule for the cross-reference token and register a value converter that strips the $ sign.

```
ElementRef: [Element|ReferenceID];
ReferenceID hidden(): '$' ID;
```

The value converter is responsible for the conversion between the abstract syntax (the ID) and the concrete syntax ($ID) for your tokens. Please refer to the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#valueconverter) for details.

Comment: Is ReferenceID a terminal or a datatype rule? It looks like a rule, but then won't it allow whitespace after the sigil?

Comment: That's what the hidden() clause is used for. It forbids any WS or comment tokens in the data type rule ReferenceID.